# color gets washed out in lighting

Tags: opengl, colors, lighting

[image]

I am supposed to have a gold coin at the centre, but my colors are getting washed out as a result of the lighting, is there anyway I could avoid it?

```
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
GLfloat light[] = {1,1,1,1};
GLfloat light_position[] = {50,100,200,1};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,light);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_position);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
```

and the cylinder is drawn with
        GLUquadricObj* qd = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricNormals(qd, GLU_SMOOTH);
    gluQuadricTexture(qd, GL_TRUE);
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(qd, GLU_FILL);
    gluDisk(qd, 0, 1, 20, 20);

```
GLUquadricObj* q = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricNormals(q, GLU_SMOOTH);
gluQuadricTexture(q, GL_TRUE);
gluQuadricDrawStyle(q, GLU_FILL);
gluCylinder(q,1,1,1,20,20);
```

the colors are

```
        GLfloat c[4];
c[0] = m_kd.R();
c[1] = m_kd.G();
c[2] = m_kd.B();
c[3] = 1;
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, c);
```

also I cannot turn the coin (cylinder), or else I would have a part of the coin black, anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: What happens if you make the coin's color darker? For example, you could multiply each of them by 0.5, or 0.1, or whatever.

Comment: blue works, but I do not want a blue coin

Comment: What I mean is, what if you just take the current color and multiply it by a value between 0 and 1?

Comment: it works if I multiply it by 0.3, but that's kinda darker than I wanted, I wonder if there is anything else I can do

Comment: You only have so much range to work with. In the fixed-function pipeline everything is clamped to 0.0-1.0. The usual solution these days is to use High Dynamic Range, where you can exceed the normal 0.0-1.0... you have to re-map the colors after lighting for display on normal monitors though, this is done through tone mapping. Since this is quite complicated, I would suggest that you simply use dimmer lights, or modify the attenuation function so that they falloff more quickly.